# Приложение падает после возврата из свернутого (кнопкой Home) состояния

Tags: android, activity, runtime, activity-life-cycle

Можно ли понять из стека ошибок, что нужно сделать что-то конкретное, или много чего может быть?

```
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.examp/com.example.examp.History}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.examp/databases/DBhistory already closed
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:957)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example.examp/databases/DBhistory already closed
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:240)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.requery(SQLiteQuery.java:148)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.requery(SQLiteCursor.java:535)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:3805)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3826)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
12-15 21:01:12.025: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  ... 10 more
```

Comment: Дословно - БД уже закрыта. Видать вы пытаетесь что-то не то с ней сделать. Например запрос сделать не открыв заново

Answer (score 0):

Причина скорее всего в методе onStart() , onRestart() или onResume(), и нужно проверить код, связанный с запросами в бд.